# How to get data from related object in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, database

I'm novice in JS and Angular. I'm facing issues getting data from a JSON file. Here is how the structure looks:
[image]

My service looks like this:

```
(function(){
angular.module('models')
.service('lessonService', function ($http, Backand) {

    var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
    var objectName = ['lessons/', 'subCategories', 'lessons_categories_switch'];
    function getUrlAllLessons () {
        return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName[0];
    };
    /*All Lessons*/
    getLessons = function () {
        return $http.get(getUrlAllLessons());
    };
    /*Subcategories*/
    function getUrlSubcategories () {
        return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName[1];
    };
    getCategories = function () {
        return $http.get(getUrlSubcategories());
    };
    /*Category Lesson Swith*/
    function getUrlSwitch () {
        return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName[2];
    };
    getSwitch = function () {
        return $http.get(getUrlSwitch());
    };
    return {
        getLessons: getLessons,
        getCategories: getCategories,
        getSwitch: getSwitch
    };
})

})();
```

My controller is the following:

```
    (function(){
    angular.module('appLessons', ['backand'])   
    .controller('lessonCtrl', function($scope, Backand, lessonService){
        $scope.lessons = [];
        $scope.subCategories = [];
        $scope.switches = [];   
        function getAllLessons() {
            lessonService.getLessons()
                .then(function (result) {
                $scope.lessons = result.data.data;
            });
        };
        function getAllSubCategories() {
            lessonService.getCategories()
                .then(function (result) {
                $scope.subCategories = result.data.data;
            });
        };
        function getAllSwitch() {
            lessonService.getSwitch()
                .then(function (result) {
                $scope.switches = result.data.data;
            });
        };    
        getAllLessons();
        getAllSubCategories();
        getAllSwitch();
    })    
    .controller('lessonDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'Backand', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, Backand) {
        $http.get(Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/lessons/' + $routeParams.id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.lesson = data;
            $scope.code = $scope.lesson.youtubeVideoCode;
        });
        $scope.closeLeftBar = function (){
            var categoryList = $('.left-lessons');
            categoryList.hide();
        };    
    }])
})();
```

And I'm trying to get all the lessons' name which belong to one of the subcategories.

In the view I have this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in subCategories">
    <div ng-show="category" class="col-md-3 lesson-tile">
        <h2>{{ category.name }} </h2> // this works
        <div ng-repeat="lesson in category.lessons">
            <div ng-show="lesson" class="col-md-3 lesson-tile">
                <h2>{{ lesson.name }} </h2> // I have problems here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I wrong? Any help is appreciated, thank to you all.

Comment: subCategories includes data for Lessons ?

Comment: Another thing i noticed that lesson doesn't have name property. May be try {{ lesson.title }}

Comment: subCategories doesn't include data for lessons, I used the lessons_categories_switch to create many to many relations. This is why I'm having problems... I don't know how to relate back from the switch to subcategories and lessons.

Comment: you're right, but {{ lesson.title }} doesn't work either... :(

Comment: @photoscene: could you post the complete json array of  `subCategories` and if possible can you replicate the same on plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: @photoscene - getAllLessons(); fetches the lesson related to sub-categories ?

Comment: it fetches only the lessons. The lessons are connected with the categories through the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't `lessons` prop inside your `category`. You should include or check all lessons and show if it by category.

Can you try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in subCategories">
    <div ng-show="category" class="col-md-3 lesson-tile">
        <h2>{{ category.name }} </h2> // this works
        <div ng-repeat="lesson in lessons">
            <div ng-show="checkCategory(category,lesson)" class="col-md-3 lesson-tile">
                <h2>{{ lesson.name }} </h2> // I have problems here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ng Function:

```
$scope.checkCategory = function(currentCategory,currentLesson){
    console.log(currentCategory);
    console.log(currentLesson);
    console.log($scope.switches);
    if($filter('filter')($scope.switches, {category : currentCategory.id + "", lesson: currentLesson.id + ""}).length > 0 )
        return true; 
    return false;
};
```

Ps: Filter can be change your json object. Maybe you should filter category something like this:

`{Id : currentCategory.Id}`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: please add console.log inside checkCategory and share your 'currentCategory'- 'currentLesson'-'switches'. i think filter not working and ng-show always false.

Comment: where should I put it  (inside the if?) and what should i log to the console?

Comment: If I put console log inside the if then it outputs the titles to the site... How is it possible? Without it it doesn't work...

Comment: edited. i wonder your object inside switches. Our filter result probably false. so console.log not working inside.

Comment: The output for switches is 3 object arrays, which contains the following: category: "1", id: 1, lesson: "1"

Comment: is "1" your category id? but currentCategory is object. Is there any property (Id) inside this object. Maybe we must change category : currentCategory.Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113030/discussion-between-photoscene-and-a-u-b).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a JSfiddle with mock data may help to understand your issue.

Your HTML template would indicate you need lessons available on your subCategories. So your data-source should look something like this:

```
$scope.subCategories = [
    {
        name : 'category-name-a',
        lessons : [
            {
                name : 'lesson-name-1'
            },
            {
                name : 'lesson-name-2'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```